# Can a WPF-app be opened and have a parameter passed to it from a hyperlink in an email?

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink

Colleagues will receive emails which are pertinent to a specific sample, and the sample can be searched in the WPF-app, but the aim is to have a link in the email which opens the app with the sample already loaded.

I can achieve this in the command line by passing command line arguments to the Startup method in App.xaml.cs with the following format, where `012345` is the sample number:

> C:\Users\yawatauma\source\tfs\myApp\myApp\bin\Release\myApp.exe 012345

but this doesn't work as a hyperlink in an email. In an email hyperlink I have only managed to get to opening the app without arguments, with a hyperlink path like this:

> C:\Users\yawatauma\source\tfs\myApp\myApp\bin\Release\myApp.exe

What is the correct syntax for opening a local WPF app and passing an argument to it via hyperlink? 
 Is what I'm trying to achieve possible with WPF, or would it have to be a web app?

Comment: For hyperlink did you try to put the complete string under quotes: "C:\Users\yawatauma\source\tfs\myApp\myApp\bin\Release\myApp.exe 012345"

Comment: I did try this, no luck

Comment: I don't think this is an app type issue, or a syntax issue.  It's an issue with how the email application is sending the link.  It is simply not parsing out the args, it's just sending the whole string as the file address.